# GitHub Pageのjekyllが手元と違う出力をします

Tags: github-pages, jekyll

[GithubPage](https://defineprogram.github.io/)

手元だと、"記事一覧"が2つ出たりしない上に、数式も正しく表示されます。
しかし、リモート上だと違う結果になってしまいます。
jekyllは最新版を使っています。
何が問題なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

トップページで記事一覧がふたつ表示されているのは、ページの `layout` が `post` になっているからかもしれません。今回使っているテーマの [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) では `home` が index.html 用のレイアウトのようです。

[この記事](https://defineprogram.github.io/jekyll/2019/12/05/welcome-to-jekyll.html)で数式が表示されてないのは、MathJax を HTTP でロードしようとしているので Mixed Content と判定されてロード失敗しているのではないでしょうか。更に `cdn.mathjax.org` は[既に廃止されている](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/)ため、他に乗り換える必要があります。

また現在 `./_site` が git push されていますが、`./site` の内容物は Jekyll によって自動生成されるもので、通常は `.gitignore` するものです。コミットの diff が見づらくなることにもつながるので、ignore しておくと良いです。

Comment: これは、jekyll buildで、remote側にアップロードする用にする処理を忘れていたので、それを実行して./_siteが編集された感じです

Comment: 数式が表示されない問題は解決しました！
ありがとうございました。